# Quarkus-Mandrel native build running forever

Tags: quarkus, quarkus-native

Just starting with quarkus-mandrel to multistage docker build for a quarkus-resteasy example.
Mac M1 pro - macOS Monterey - 8Cpu and 32GB memory
Docker Deskop - VM - 6cpu Memory 16GB

```
FROM quay.io/quarkus/ubi-quarkus-mandrel:21.3-java11 AS build
USER root

COPY --chown=quarkus:quarkus mvnw /code/mvnw
COPY --chown=quarkus:quarkus .mvn /code/.mvn
COPY --chown=quarkus:quarkus pom.xml /code/

USER quarkus
WORKDIR /code
RUN ./mvnw -B org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:3.1.2:go-offline
COPY src /code/src
RUN ./mvnw package -Pnative -Dquarkus.native.native-image-xmx=14g -Drelease.version=1.0

## Stage 2 : create the docker final image
FROM quay.io/quarkus/quarkus-micro-image:1.0
WORKDIR /work/
COPY --from=build /code/target/*-runner /work/application

# set up permissions for user `1001`
RUN chmod 775 /work /work/application \
  && chown -R 1001 /work \
  && chmod -R "g+rwX" /work \
  && chown -R 1001:root /work

EXPOSE 9080
USER 1001

CMD ["./application", "-Dquarkus.http.host=0.0.0.0"]
```

Docker Build

```
docker build  -f src/main/docker/Dockerfile.multistage -t epp .
```

Build stuck at

```
=> [build 10/10] RUN ./mvnw package -Pnative -Dquarkus.native.native-image-xmx=14g -Drelease.version=1.0                                                                                                                                                               3184.7s
 => => # [INFO] Building jar: /code/target/enterpiseplanprofile-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
 => => # [INFO]
 => => # [INFO] --- quarkus-maven-plugin:2.8.1.Final:build (default) @ enterpiseplanprofile ---
 => => # [WARNING] [io.quarkus.config] Unrecognized configuration key "quarkus.hibernate-orm.database.generation" was provided; it will be ignored; verify that the dependency extension for this configuration is set or that you did not make a typo
 => => # [INFO] [io.quarkus.deployment.pkg.steps.JarResultBuildStep] Building native image source jar: /code/target/enterpiseplanprofile-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-native-image-source-jar/enterpiseplanprofile-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-runner.jar
 => => # [INFO] [io.quarkus.deployment.pkg.steps.NativeImageBuildStep] Building native image from /code/target/enterpiseplanprofile-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-native-image-source-jar/enterpiseplanprofile-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-runner.jar
```

Appreciate any guidance..

Thanks
Raj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update 21.9**:
Work in https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus-images/issues/83 has completed and multi-arch images are now available.

**Original answer:**
The native image builder images are currently only x86 and the emulation of x86 on M1 would appear to be incredibly slow.

I briefly tried to boot up a multi-arch `registry.access.redhat.com/ubi8` image, and I was able to emulate the commands that the builder image would execute (assuming the right aarch64 dependencies installed). I was able to build native executables without any issues there.

We're working to provide multi-arch versions of the builder images, but we're not there yet.

Comment: Thanks @Galder. Any git repo I can setup a watch to follow for updates ?

Comment: @funtoos [the official quarkus github](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus)

Comment: [quarkus-images](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus-images) is the repo where the magic sauce for building container images lives. The multi-arch image work is being tracked in [this issue](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus-images/issues/83). I'll update the answer once images are up.

Comment: @Galder, Finally got my hands on a linux machine (loaner). Had a question. If I make a build with podman using the above dockerfile and setting application.properties to deploy on openshift am I on the right path ? I

```
podman build -f src/main/docker/Dockerfile.multistage .
```

Comment: I only see the image being created in local repo.

Comment: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus-images/issues/83 has been completed and multi-arch images are now available online.